# Unable to connect a Run A Script in Selenium using IE Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Trying to Run a Script in Luna Eclipse using IE Driver
and getting the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Here is the code trying to Run:

```
package com.newpack;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class SecondClass {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,"https://www.google.co.in"); 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","M:\\workspace\\IEDriver.exe");



    WebDriver driver ;
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String expectedTitle = "Google";
    String actualTitle = "";

    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();


    if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }


    driver.close();


    System.exit(0);

}
```

}

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Please cross check that you are using right driver. if you are machine is of 32bit, then you should use 32 bit IE driver only.

Answer (score 0):

try once following steps

Got to

1. internet options>>Security>>
2. click on:"Reset all zones to default level"
3. ensure that the 'Enable protected mode' checkbox is ticked for all the four zones. Like i.e Internet, Local internet, Trusted Sites, Restricted Sites.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer needs to be configured first in order to successfully run a selenium script.

Make sure you complete all the following steps:

1. Go to Internet Options > Security and enable "Protected Mode" for all the 4 zones: **Internet**, **Local internet**, **Trusted Sites**, **Restricted Sites**.
2. Also, click on **Custom Level** for all 4 zones and reset **Recent Custom Settings** to same level, say "Medium" or "High".

If this does not work, please update your IEDriverServer from [Selenium Official Downloads](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)